# Python input() does not work after ENTER on input - PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, pycharm

My python code is simple

```
print("Username: ", end='')
user = input()
password = getpass("Password: ")
```

when I run it on the terminal in PyCharm, after entering the username the program is stuck in the second line. I can't enter the password. While if I run it in debug mode I can proceed. Weird. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can u show your getpass function

Comment: @skaul05 presumably https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html

Comment: When you say you can't enter it, what do you mean? If you mean you don't see what you're typing, that's the expected behaviour.

Comment: Try running script from OS command-line — may be an issue with the pycharm terminal.

Comment: @skaul05 `from getpass import getpass`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I type my email as username then I press ENTER

Comment: ...and then what? What's the *problem*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't type the password. It seems like if it can't exit the `input()` function

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you mean by *"can't type the password"*. What do you do? What happens? What did you expect instead?

Comment: first you could add `print(text)` after `input()` to see if it exited from `input()`. You could also try with `input()` instead of `getpass()` to check if problem makes `getpass()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe have you tried it in PyCharm? Because the questions states *exactly* what happens.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I run the program (inside PyCharm). I type my username then ENTER. What I expect is to have the `Password: ` printed on my terminal and then type the password next to it.

Comment: What you're describing is not seeing the prompt, which is not necessarily the same as not being able to type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely due to the way the terminal works in PyCharm. Try enabling "Terminal Emulation".

Open the run configurations and toggle this checkbox:

[image: Run Configuration, Terminal Emulation]